# KVM/libvirt gets stuck while using ZFS

Tags: virtual-machine, fedora, qemu, kvm, zfs

A few weeks ago i set up my system using Fedora 31 and Cockpit and KVM/libvirt/qemu as host for my virtual machines.
I have 8 virtual machines at all, one for every service, but only one is not doing it's job.
There is one virtual machine, using Debian 10 and ZFS, and it was doing it's job really well, until it's first reboot.
After the reboot it's getting stucked. So what did i do? I have set up a new Debian 10 system, installing ZFS again, rebooting to get the kernel module zfs running, and another reboot --> System get's stucked after receiving "Welcome to GRUB!" message.
Any other virtual machine is running fine, but when i try to create one with nothing else installed, just ZFS it's having issues.
What's the problem, and does someone have some ideas?
First i'll proceed with using Debian 9, and disabling any updates, maybe there is some problem.

Here i got some log, i received by libvirtd.service when this happens.

```
internal error: End of file from qemu monitor
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyDMZ.png)